# Are std::vector emplace_back and push_back thread-safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

If I have a function that only do emplace_back or push_back on a global vector with unique_ptr as a values, will it be thread-safe or I have to use mutexes? Is mutex the only way to make it thread safe?

```
void (T param)
{
globalVector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(param));
//or globalVector.push_back (std::make_unique<T>(param));
}
```

And  if it only be vector of T?

```
void (T param)
{
globalVector.emplace_back(param);
//or globalVector.push_back (param);
}
```

Comment: No standard container is thread-safe.

Comment: @Peter it is possible for an object to have an internal mutex and be thread-safe.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I'm using standard vector. So adding lock mutex before push_back/emplace_back is the only way to make it thread-safe?

Comment: @Bruice yes, as the answer states. In general with any lib you should assume no extra thread safety guarantees other than the ones explicitly mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

> will it be thread-safe

No

> or I have to use mutexes?

Yes

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety) for thread-safety of standard containers.

Comment: And is mutex the only way, if talking about std?

Comment: @Bruice it's the most generic way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this toy example that illustrates the critical part that eg a `vector<int>::push_back` might do:

```
struct broken_toy_vector {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int* data;
    void push_back(int x){
        if (size+1 > capacity) {
            int* temp = new int[size+1];
            // copy from data to temp
            temp[size] = x;
            size += 1;
            delete data;
            data = temp;
        } else {
            throw "not implemented";
        }
    }
};
```

A `std::vector` is surely not a `broken_toy_vector`, but when the new size exceeds current capacity then a vector needs to reallocate. There is no good reason for `std::vector` to make `push_back` thread-safe, because that would incur overhead in any single-threaded usage. Further, also with more than one thread, often you don't want synchronisation on the lowest level. Consider:

```
 for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
      vect.push_back(i);
 }
```

Locking a mutex in every iteration would be extremely wasteful.

TL;DR

No. It is not safe to call `std::vector::push_back` concurrently from different threads. A container that protects any acces to its data, would be of limited use, because the user has no control over granularity of the locking.